# Where to find the class System.Windows.UIElement

Tags: c#

I am searching for the reference `System.Windows.UIElement` but I cannot find it in the .NET environment. I need to use the type or name `UIElement`. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Please verify the type of project where you are trying to reference UIElement.

Comment: I think, you are using .Net 2.0. It's available 3.0 onwards with WPF project/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you search [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) for `UIElement` you'll find the following information [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx):

- class `UIElement` is in the `System.Windows` namespace, so you'll have to use `System.Windows.UIElement` or add a `using System.Windows` directive
- `UIElement` is in the `PresentationCore` assembly, so you'll have to add a reference to `PresentationCore.dll`
- `UIElement` is available in .NET versions 3.0 and newer

Answer (score 3):

I expect you need to add a reference to the `PresentationCore` assembly.